# Use Lampp mysqldump as default in php call

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, mysql

tricky question and I don't know if SO is the good space (maybe AskUbuntu ? or SuperUser ?)

I've set my Lampp on my ubuntu in `/opt/lampp/`

Problem, when I need to call direct bin as `mysqldump`, I end up calling the default installed one on my ubuntu, not the one linked to my lampp :

> $ mysqldump --user=root test
>
> mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect
>   to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
>   when trying to connect

As you can see, it check for `/var/run`.
If I want to use the good one, I should specify the path :

> $ /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump --user=root test
>
> -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.21, for Linux (x86_64)

I could use the full path in my PHP call, but my PHP prod server will then not work.

How can I set the Lampp bin as default to be used by php with `exec('mysqldump')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have several choices to do what you want.

- You could create a configuration file that depends on your environement (local, dev, preprod, prod ...). This file may declare an array of configurations, one of which is the path of the executable you need. Your php code will know the environment by checking a global variable, for instance `$_SERVER`, which can be set in your web server's vhost file. I think that's the clean way of doing.
- You could hardcode a path for you executable (let's say `/home/www/mysqldump`) and create a symbolic link with `ln -s` (if I remember right, or check the man page) between your environment's executable `/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump` and `/home/www/mysqldump`. You have to prepare all your environments that way. I think it's a bit ugly but it's quick.

I am sure there are tons of other solutions.

Comment: Not the answer I was seeking, as it'll bind the code to my machine; I was hopping for the other way, machine changed to follow the code. But I'll accept this for now :-/